# .NET - execute a lambda on another computer

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, nhlambdaextensions

I've recently implemented an IronRuby web service application for a client, to replace an existing C# .NET DLL. What the client forgot to mention was that in the mean time they implemented a new version of the DLL, with a new API based on lambda expressions. And made sure all calls (thousands :( ) use the new syntax. So now I need to implement a replacement .NET DLL which receives Func/Actions and executes them on a remote server.

Now I'm a Ruby/Perl guy and have little knowedge of advanced .NET. I don't quite get the difference between Expressions and lambas. I know LINQ to SQL can execute expressions on a remote SQL server. Can it execute lambdas too? Can I use the same approach (whatever it is) in my scenario?

Generally any pointers/ideas/solutions are welcome.

Thanks, Frederik

Comment: Lambda functions aren't run remotely, unless that's where they were defined. They're not some protocol, but a language feature. Same goes for expressions. See my answer below!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for; but at least I can try to provide some insights into the difference between `Expression` and lambda functions, both of which are language features of the mainstream .NET languages (C#, VB.NET).

---

Basically, a **lambda function** is an anonymous (unnamed) function that can be declared inside the scope of another function. In C# (language version 3), it would be declared like this:

> **`(`** *parameter list* **`)`** **`=>`** *function body*

For example:

```
void Foo()
{
    // two equivalent lambda functions with one double parameter 'x' each:
    var square = (double x) => x * x;
    var square2 = (double x) => { return x * x; };

    // lambda function that doesn't take any arguments:
    var doSomething = () => { Console.WriteLine("Hello."); }
}
```

(Note that e.g. `square` is not the name of the lambda function, but of the variable that references it. The lambda function itself does not have any name in the way that method `void Foo()` has!)

Something very similar was already possible with C# version 2, called *anonymous delegates*:

```
delegate(double x) { return x * x; }  // is equivalent to: (double x) => x * x
```

---

**Expressions** were added to .NET with LINQ (in the namespace `System.Linq.Expressions`). Basically, they're simple data structures that describe, as an *abstract syntax tree* (AST), any computation as can be expressed e.g. with C# or VB.NET. Take for example:

```
// case 1. IEnumerable<int>:
IEnumerable<int> xs = ...;
IEnumerable<int> queryXs = from x in xs where x > 0 select x;

// case 2. IQueryable<int>:
IQueryable<int>  ys = ...;
IEnumerable<int> queryYs = from y in ys where y > 0 select y;
```

These two queries are identical, except that `ys` is of type `IQueryable<int>` instead of `IEnumerable<int>`. The C# compiler will translate the above two queries into different code, namely:

```
// case 1. IEnumerable<int>:
IQueryable<int> xs = ...;
IEnumerable<int> queryXs = xs.Where<int>(delegate (int x) { return x > 0; });

// case 2. IQueryable<int>:
IEnumerable<int> ys = ...;
ParameterExpression yParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y");
IEnumerable<int> queryYs.Where<int>(
    Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
        Expression.GreaterThan(
            yParameter,
            Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int))),
        new ParameterExpression[] { yParameter }));
```

If you study the latter, you will see that for the query of the `IQueryable<int>`, the compiler has output the parsed query as a data structure that describes the query. On the other hand, for the query against `IEnumerable<int>`, it has simply output code that performs the query. It turns out that the compiler does the special magic of producing what it has parsed as an *expression tree* only with the `IQueryable<T>` type.

Expressions and `IQueryable<T>` therefore allow you to analyse a query at run-time and perform optimizations and other transformations on it before it is actually run. This is heavily used e.g. by LINQ to SQL to write intelligent, optimized SQL queries:

Imagine a database was asked for all rows where some column `x` is > 0.

- If the database were an `IEnumerable<int>` (that really is simplifying it a lot, I know, but bear with me), all rows would have to be fetched and then filtered by the `.Where(delegate (int x) { ... })` method.
- If the database were an `IQueryable<int>`, the `Expression` output by the compiler would be analysed and transformed into an SQL query at run-time such that it would include an appropriate `WHERE x > 0` clause and only produce the desired rows right away.

---

If you're interested in the internals of / parsing expression trees, have a look at the in-depth blog series by Bart De Smet, starting with [The IQueryable tales - LINQ to LDAP - Part 0: Introduction](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/04/05/the-iqueryable-tales-linq-to-ldap-part-0.aspx).